# Data type mismatch in criteria expression in WPF Application

Tags: c#, wpf, oledb

Please help me out in this error.
I am using access database in C# and developing WPF application. Here, I am writing updating query and i got the below error :-

> "Data type mismatch in criteria expression".

Here, Retail and Cut_Off both are checkbox. I added it later.When I added checkbox later it gives me this error.

I stored checkbox value like below :-

```
cmentity.Retail = chkRetailIndividualBidder.IsChecked.Value.ToString();
cmentity.Cut_Off = chkCutOff.IsChecked.Value.ToString();
```

Below code wrote in Clientmasterrepository.cs file

```
    public int UpdateForAllClientInfo(ClientMaster cmentity)
    {

        string strQuery = "UPDATE ClientMaster SET " +
            "Applied_Quantity = '" + cmentity.Applied_Quantity + "', " +
            "Amount = '" + cmentity.Amount + "', " +
            "Cheque_in_Favour = '" + cmentity.Cheque_in_Favour + "', " +
            "Retail_Individual_Bidder = '" + cmentity.Retail + "', " +
            "Cut_Off = '" + cmentity.Cut_Off + "' " +
           "WHERE IsDeleted = " + 0;
        return oConnectionClass.ExecuteNonQuery(strQuery);
     }
```

below code wrote in connection.cs file:-

```
    public int ExecuteNonQuery(string strQuery)
    {
        OleDbConnection oleDbConnection = new OleDbConnection(strConnectionString);
        OleDbCommand oleDbCommand = new OleDbCommand(strQuery, oleDbConnection);

        oleDbCommand.CommandText = strQuery;
        oleDbCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        oleDbConnection.Open();
        oleDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        oleDbConnection.Close();
        return 1;
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure your all columns are character typed in `SET` part?

Comment: Yes , I am 100% sure.

Comment: when I debug I got this :- "UPDATE ClientMaster SET Applied_Quantity = '20', Amount = '2000', Cheque_in_Favour = 'SSS', Retail_Individual_Bidder = 'True', Cut_Off = 'True' WHERE IsDeleted = 0"

Comment: Are you sure that 'True' and 'False' are what the values are stored as in the database? If they are bit fields like isDeleted, then you would need to coerce their values to 0 and 1. I could post an answer based on this assumption, but if you can show the type definition for cmentity it would help.

Comment: I am using access database and I stored checkbox value in yes/no datatype.

Comment: OK.I did it. Thanks bro.